# gsutil: No such file or directory on startup

Tags: bash, snap, startup

I have VM that runs on linux 18.04.01 and that executes a startup script which includes gsutil :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
source bin/ci/colors

composer run-script --no-dev build-parameters

gsutil -q cp "gs://gcp-myproject/myappname/parameters.yml" "app/config/parameters.yml"

bin/console cache:warmup --no-interaction
```

that sometimes (let's say 1 or 2 times out of 3) fails with this error :

`line 7: /snap/bin/gsutil: No such file or directory`

i have supposed that it was because of the daily refresh of the snap packages, but sometimes it happens too many times daily

Comment: You may also want to update your 18.04 system. You are way behind in update the current is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS